# stage dimensions from imported class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dimensions, stage

**I** want to call stage.stagewidth/stage.stagehieght from imported class.
here is my code hope any one can fix it or tell me how to do it

```
package 
 {
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import multyLoader;
  public class program extends MovieClip
    {
     private var theLoader:multyLoader = new multyLoader();
     public function program()
       {
      // constructor code-----------------
      theLoader.My_Loader(mc_loaderHolder,myXML.IMAGE[1].@URL);
       }
     }
 }
```

and the multyLoader.as file code is

```
 package 
 {
  public class multyLoader extends MovieClip
   {
    public function multyLoader()
     {
      trace(any);
     }
    public function My_Loader(loading_holder,myLoaderURL:String)
     {
      // pla pla code
      loading_holder.x = (stage.stageWidth - loading_holder.width) / 2; // get Error #1009 or stage not found.
      loading_holder.y = (stage.stageHeight - loading_holder.height) / 2; // get Error
     }      
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference the Stage from your `multyLoader` instance, then it needs to be on the display list first. The safest way to do that is to listen for the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event and only reference the stage after that event has fired.

```
public function My_Loader(loading_holder, myLoaderURL:String){
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
}

protected function onAddedToStage(e:Event){
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    loading_holder.x = (stage.stageWidth - loading_holder.width) / 2;
    // etc...
}
```

You could also just make sure to only call the `My_Loader` function after you are sure `theLoader` has been added to the display list. It's not always as straightforward as it seems though.

A third option, if you don't want `theLoader` to be on the display list for whatever reason, would be to pass `theLoader` a reference to the stage from the parent class. You could add it as an argument to your `My_Loader` function.

```
public function My_Loader(loading_holder, myLoaderURL:String, myStage:Stage){
    loading_holder.x = (myStage.stageWidth - loading_holder.width) / 2;
    // etc...
}
```

calling it from the parent class like this:

```
theLoader.My_Loader(mc_loaderHolder, myXML.IMAGE[1].@URL, this.stage);
```